# Find a basis of the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$ generated by the vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis of the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$ generated by the vectors $$v_1=(1,1,2,0),v_2=(-1,0,1,0),v_3=(2,-2,0,0),v_4=(0,0,-1,2)$$

First of all I wrote these vectors as rows of a matrix then applied the following transformations to reduce the matrix in row echelon form:-
$R_2+R_1$ & $R_3-2R_1$
Then $R_3+4R_2$ and finally $\frac{1}{10}R_3$
Then I wrote the non zero rows in row echelon form as $B={(1,1,2,0),(0,1,3,0),(0,0,1,0)}$ which forms basis .
Am I right here?

Comment: Your $v_4$ has a nonzero entry in the last coordinate, but none of your three transformed vectors do.  So you made a mistake.  I think all those 4 original vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: They are linearly independent so they generate $R^4$. R1+R2, R3-2R1, R3+4R2,R3/8, R3+R4. This steps shows they are linearly independent.

Comment: What if in case of vectors which are not linearly independent? What process should I go through?

Comment: Then I guess I did mistake while reducing the matrix in row echelon form.

Comment: @SaeidAli I guess $\frac{1}{10} R_3$ should be done in order to get the basis as $(1,1,2,0),(0,1,3,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,2)$

Comment: from (1,1,2,0),(0,1,3,0),(0,-4,-4,0),(0,0,-1,2) after applying R3+4R2 we have the third one equal to (0,0,8,0) which is R3/8. As I see this the part that we do not have in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the vectors given in the problem, we can define a set: $$A = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$$

Remember the definition of a Basis set:

Given: V is a vector space and B is a subset of V, we say that B is a basis of V IFF $V = span(B)$ and B is linearly independent.

Row-Reducing the matrix form of the set A yields: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2&0\\1&0&-2&0\\2&1&0&-1\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$ <=>$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Since each column contains a leading "1",  we can say that the set A is linearly independent.

This result implies that the set A itself satisfies the definition of a basis.

$B = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$